# Batch file - The syntax of the command is incorrect

Tags: batch-file

I have the following bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF 
REN D:\my data\data test\secondary-pgwslisting_delta-20150722_024306_001 secondary-pgwslisting_delta-_%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,5% 
ECHO
PAUSE
```

However I get the syntax of the command is incorrect error. I want to append the current datetime - 7h to the filename. 
Example: 
filename: secondary-pgwslisting_delta-20150722_024306_001

I want to rename 20150722_024306 to 20150731_024306_001 (July 31,2015 - 2:43:06 AM) (always get the current time - 7h)
Can you help me with the correct syntax? 
Thanks

Comment: Put quotes around path\filenames. Currently you try to rename `D:\my` to `data\data` and add some additional (invalid) parameters

Comment: try with `REN "D:\my data\data test\secondary-pgwslisting_delta-20150722_024306_001" "secondary-pgwslisting_delta-_%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,5%"`

Comment: In addition to @stephan comment, on wrapping the filename with quotes, first proceed step by step checking the result of  `echo %date:~10,4%` first, which in my system returns an error because the result of `%date%` command is customizable.

Comment: Removing `@echo off` avoids almost 90% of such syntax-error questions...

Comment: Thank all for your supports, after update as @npocmaka I get an another issue which is "The system cannot find the path specified."